# Плагин kk Star Ratings для Wordpress - как в MySql задать начальный рейтинг всем постам

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Для Wordpress есть плагин kk star ratings https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/kk-star-ratings/ который служит для рейтинга постов.

При каждой новой оценке на сайте, в таблицу wp_postmeta добавляется записи

```
meta_id  post_id  meta_key       meta_value
59520    19524    _kksr_ratings  5
59521    19524    _kksr_casts    1
59522    19524    _kksr_ips      YToxOntpOjA7czoxMzoiMTcyLjY4...
59523    19524    _kksr_avg      5.00
```

Как задать начальный рейтинг для всех постов с помощью команды SQL?

Comment: И что вы будете делать при добавлении новых постов? Вам надо искать хук в плагине, который ставит начальный рейтинг.

Comment: Благодарю, за идею. Но в данном случае, необходимость только в том чтобы проставить автоматом рейтинг к уже существующим тысячам постов.                                                                                                 
Скорей всего это как-то можно сделать через MySql. Для одного поста это можно сделать. А как сделать для диапазона постов к примеру с поста с ID 12 до ID 10000?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функции Wordpress:

```
   function upd_meta_ratings(){
    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    ];
    $post_list = new WP_Query($args); // Вытащит все посты типа post с БД
    if($post_list->have_posts()) : while ($post_list->have_posts()) : $post_list->the_post(); // Запускаем цикл, в котором проверяем есть ли рейтинг у поста, если нету, то добавляем нужное метаполе
        $id = get_the_ID();
        if(empty(get_post_meta($id,'_kksr_avg',true))) add_post_meta($id,'_kksr_avg', '5.00');
        if(empty(get_post_meta($id,'_kksr_ratings',true))) add_post_meta($id,'_kksr_ratings', '5');
        if(empty(get_post_meta($id,'_kksr_casts',true))) add_post_meta($id,'_kksr_casts', '1');
    endwhile;
    endif;
}
add_action('update_my_meta','upd_meta_ratings');
do_action('update_my_meta');
```

Вставляйте код выше в файл темы, что используете, functions.php, далее один раз посетите любую страницу сайта, мета ключи апдейтнутся и код можно закоментрировать и оставить на будущеее или удалить.

Comment: Спасибо, задумка отличная. Попробовал на практике вставить в functions.php - выдало ошибку "Can't use function return value in write context"

Comment: А где вы ее использывали\запускали? Так как ошибка из разряда использывания в неправильном месте. Рекомендую поместить код в конец файла `functions.php` темы, что используется, и там же выполнить, строчка из кода  `do_action('update_my_meta');` , или поместиь в файл темплейта для простых постов. Достаточно после етого раз обновить страницу любую или ту, где вызывали функцию.
Скорее всего в functions.php при вставке функции вы ее вставили перед закрытием предидущей, тоесть до } , так как на локалке для уверенности проверил все работает.

Comment: Спасибо, но всеравно не сработало. Я извиняюсь, возможно я немного не точно дал описание: При каждой новой оценке на сайте, в таблицу wp_postmeta добавляется запись   https://imgur.com/a/H5P13

Comment: Попробуйте внутри использывать `add_post_meta()`, на атомате писал, ошибка в том, что `update_post_meta` фактически работает, если ключ есть, а у нас их нету)) Проверка `empty(get_post_meta($id,'_kksr_avg',true))` , код после нее работает если ключа не найдено или он пустой, а если логически смотреть, что у постов нету ключа, то нужно его добавить, а не оновить. Ответ оновил.

Comment: Благодарю, но к сожалению по прежнему не сработал код - выдает ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле все очень просто (главное сделать все аккуратно). Есть таблица с постами `wp_posts`, рейтинг, как вы указали, сохраняется в `wp_postmeta`.  По сути нам нужен только список `post_id` для "меты". Значит чтобы поставить "начальный" рейтинг достаточно выполнить 4 запроса `INSERT ... SELECT` (для каждого мета-параметра). Вроде такого:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` (`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`)
    SELECT `ID`, '_kksr_ratings', '__значение по-умолчанию__'
        FROM `wp_posts`
        WHERE `post_type` = 'post'
```

Естественно нужно поменять `__значение по-умолчанию__` на необходимое и сделать еще три подобных запроса с заменой "_kksr_ratings" на соответственно "_kksr_casts", "_kksr_ips", "_kksr_avg" со своими значениями по-умолчанию. Также `SELECT`-часть запроса можно изменить и генерировать случайные или зависимые от полей `wp_posts` или других таблиц значения (например можно добавить `JOIN` с условием чтобы не затронуть записи, у которых рейтинг уже задан.

P.S. **Не забудьте сделать непосредственно перед запросом резервную копию.** Любые подобные массовые действия в обход движка чреваты потерей или искажением данных.

Answer (score 0):

Sql Запросом будет примерно так, для каждого поста вставляем все 4 записи которые геренирит плагин. Из значимого

**5 AS meta_value** - 5 это оцека

**'5.00' AS meta_value** - это средняя оценка

**'закодированная строка с IP' AS meta_value** это вот та строка с ip которая на скрине, ну то есть просто вставьте ее вместо моего текста

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
   SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT p.id AS post_id, '__kksr_ratings' AS meta_key, 5 AS meta_value FROM wp_posts p
      UNION
      SELECT p.id AS post_id, '__kksr_casts' AS meta_key, 1 AS meta_value FROM wp_posts p
      UNION
      SELECT p.id AS post_id, '__kksr_ips' AS meta_key, 'закодированная строка с IP' AS meta_value FROM wp_posts p
      UNION
      SELECT p.id AS post_id, '__kksr_avg' AS meta_key, '5.00' AS meta_value FROM wp_posts p) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочий код, вставляется в functions.php 
После этого достаточно открыть один пост на сайте. Далее код можно закомментировать, иначе будет обновлять каждый раз

```
/* KK Rating update */
$post_list = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => -1, //Все записи в блоге
)); 
$j = 1;
if($post_list->have_posts()) : while ($post_list->have_posts()) : $post_list->the_post();
    $count = rand(7,20); //Кол-во проголосовавших от 7 до 20
    $stars = rand(4.5,5); //Средняя оценка от 4.5 до 5
    //Отладка
    echo '#'.$j.' - '.get_the_title($post_list->post->ID).' -'.get_the_permalink($post_list->post->ID).'<br>'.PHP_EOL;

    update_post_meta( $post_list->post->ID, '_kksr_avg', $stars );
    update_post_meta( $post_list->post->ID, '_kksr_ratings', $count * $stars );
    update_post_meta( $post_list->post->ID, '_kksr_casts', $count );
    update_post_meta( $post_list->post->ID, '_kksr_ips', 'YToxOntpOjA7czoxMzoiOTEuMTA1LjIzNy40NiI7fQ==' );
    $j++;
endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
/* KK Rating update end */
```